# Add .aspx file into solution dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, master-pages, content-pages

Can any body tell me how i can include a .aspx into a solution of asp.net project dynamically like in c# or Vb. Is there any property to accomplish this task. You comments are honored.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the scenario or more details. However you can do it as simple as adding any file by crating it and saving it in your project using IO.

Thanks.